# Embed code is not working for Chrome browser However its working on IE Browser

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, office-web-apps, office

I have a PowerPoint Presentation File and using the embed code of if I am trying to display as Iframe on my publishing pages.

This is Working on IE browser but not working for Chrome.

I have created a Article page and then added CWEP on it and Provided HTML file to the CWEP and then created a list with Rich text column and in the rich text column i am  providing the embed code.

Now using rest i am displaying the Rich text column on the Article page. I can see the PPT file in iframe on IE but in Chrome it gives me error "Sorry Something went Wrong " Sorry, you don't have access to this page. Could you guys Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Chorme uses HSTS by default. It will automatically redirect http to https.

You can try to browser the path in Chrome directly and see if it uses https and check whether you can access it.

Meanwhile, try using the “localhost” instead of the server name, see if it works.

For example, the path is "`http://sp/sites/team`", use "`http://localhost/sites/team`"

Some references abhout how to remove HSTS header:

https://superuser.com/questions/565409/how-to-stop-an-automatic-redirect-from-http-to-https-in-chrome

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277457/google-chrome-redirecting-localhost-to-https